# Sum over loop python without loops

Tags: python, function, loops, sum

I have the following code that performs a simple sum over a list. Can do this without using loops?

```
x_sph_rand = [x-1000 if x > 1000 else x for x in x_sph_rand]
```

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by `loop`. You obviously have to access each element.

Comment: You should explain your intentions. People are posting all sorts of weird answers. The simple answer is that you _should_ use (some kind of) a loop.

Comment: Are you looking for a functional/applicative approach?

    `import operator
    reduce(operator.add, [1,2,3,4])`

Comment: I think using the word `sum` has confused a lot of people. `sum(lst)` adds up all the values in `lst`, so that's what a lot of the answers seem to be about.

Answer (score 2):

`sum(x-1000 if x > 1000 else x for x in x_sph_rand)` will do it with a generator, which is a bit better, but still uses a loop... anything will use a loop behind the scenes because you can't make a sum of elements without adding each element.

If you want to formally avoid a loop notation:

```
sum(map(lambda x: x-1000 if x > 1000 else x, x_sph_rand))
```

or

```
reduce(lambda x,y : (x if x < 1000 else x - 1000) + (y if y < 1000 else y - 1000), x_sph_rand)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without an explicit loop (that is, without the `for` keyword), certainly:

```
map(lambda x: x - 1000 if x > 1000 else x, x_sph_rand)
```

Without an implicit loop, no. No matter what happens, *something* will iterate over your list.

Comment: I think you mean `map`, not `filter`, right?

Comment: Yup, my bad. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursion…

```
def recursive_sum(l, start=0):
    if l:
        return start
    else:
        return recursive_sum(l[1:], start + l[0])
```

…but since Python doesn't have tail-call optimization, this is a bad idea: you will get a stack overflow if your list is long enough.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use recursion to move through your list, but it will be quite a bit less efficient than using a loop. It will also fail on long lists, when Python hits the system recursion limit (which is 1000, by default).

Here's a function that mutates a list in place, without using a loop:

```
def f(lst, i=0):
    if i < len(lst):
        if lst[i] > 1000:
            lst[i] -= 1000
        f(lst, i+1)
```

Example output:

```
>>> l = [1,22,333,4444,55555]
>>> f(l)
>>> l
[1, 22, 333, 3444, 54555]
```